# Every isometry of a compact metric space into itself is onto

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness, isometry

Despite of being aware of the duplicates of this question, I am posting it just to have my approach verified.

Let $f:X \to X$ be an isometry on $X$. By definition, when $f(a)=f(b)$, then $ d_X(f(a),f(b))=0=d(a,b) \implies a=b$, i.e. it is injective.

The set $X$ is compact, hence it is closed and bounded. Suppose, $X-f(X)=Y \neq \emptyset$. Taking $p\in Y$, we take the minimum distance from $f(X)$ to be $\delta$.

We now take an open cover of $X$, in such a manner, that in each $G_{X_i}$, $\displaystyle\sup\{d_X(s,t): s, t \in G_{X_i}\}=\delta$. Now, let $\displaystyle\sup\{d_X(s,t): s, t \in X\}=\lambda$. We need at most $\lceil \frac{\lambda}{\delta} \rceil $ open sets. Again, by isometry, we get corresponding $\sup{d_X(f(s),f(t))}=\delta$. But, by Pigeon Hole Principle, we see that if not surjective, then the function fails to be injective due to overlapping.

I know that this "proof" is very vague and inappropriate, but I need some direction.

Another doubt: How do I prove that $f(X)$ is compact?

Attempt: $X \subset G_1\cup G_2 \cup...\cup G_n \implies f(X) \subset f(G_1) \cup ...\cup f(G_n)$. For an arbitrary $g\in G_k$, $d_X(z,g)<\beta \implies z\in G_k$ for some $\beta >0$. Now, $f(g) \in f(G_k)$ and $d_X(f(z),f(g))<\beta \implies f(z) \in f(G_k)$. We repeat this for every possible open cover.

Does this work?

Comment: The image of a compact set under a continuous function is always again compact. And $f$, being an isometry, is in particular continuous (pre-image of open sets are open).

Comment: I can sense some sort of continuity, but can't prove it. Does my proof work at all (compactness). ?

Comment: In order to show that $f(X)$ is compact, you would want to start with an arbitrary open cover of $f(X)$ and not of $X$, as you seem to do in your sketch.

Comment: Let me try to prove the continuity here in the comments, do check it.

Comment: Take $x, y \in X$ with $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. By isometry, $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$ whenever the former holds.

Comment: Now, the image of a compact set under a continuous mapping is compact. We are done.

Comment: Can you also prove this ? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91048/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-berni-waterman).

Comment: In general “closed and bounded” doesn't imply compact in a metric space.

Comment: Yes. But compactness implies boundedness, as far as I know

Comment: you shouldn't worry whether your set is bounded or not. compactness is all that matters, and all you should need in your proof

Comment: @BerniWaterman boundedness is essential for the "squeezing" as we discussed. Yes, the "compactness" does the job.

Comment: It is an essential part of the *intuition* behind the proof (also because all the compact sets that we can visualize are bounded in some sense), but it is not actually needed in the formal proof.